# Use FindBugs in Eclipse from terminal on Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, java, eclipse

Is there any way I could use Findbugs from  terminal to get all the bugs in my Java code and print it out to a text file?

I want to write a script that goes through 100 java files ( this is already done)
As I iterate through these java files, I want to use [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).

I did read that [manual](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/introduction.html), but it does not show what I want to do.

Comment: It seems to support [command line options](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#commandLineOptions), is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: @1_CR `The project file you specify should be one that was created using the GUI interface`  So I cannot run it over a project on the repository.